# Cloud function invoke not reading data

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have a basic cloud function to test using gcp, but it doesnt read any data that is passed to it, below is the code for the deployed code and the local function used to call it:

cloud function:

```
def hello_world(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        return f'Hello World!'
```

local function:

```
    import requests
    url = "https://europe-west-2/testing_response"  # url censored, cloud function called testing_response
    data = {"message":"foo"}
    response = requests.post(url,data=data)
    print(response.text)
```

running the following python produces the result 'Hello World', cant seem to figure out why.

Comment: Try adding the header **content-type: application/json** to the request.

Comment: tried this but didn't make any major changes, this was resolved by importing the json package and applying json.dumps to the data being inputted, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed by importing the [JSON package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
import json
```

And using *json.dumps* to export the value.

```
json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
```